# How to remove a tooltip when the following input disabled

Tags: css, tooltip

How can I remove the Boostrap tooltip when the following input is disabled?

```
<label class="label" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Test">
    <input type="checkbox" value="disabled" class="input" disabled>
<label>
```

First, I tried to detect whether it has a tooltip, but it seems not working. And then, set it to ''.

```
 if($(this).is('[data-toggle="tooltip"]')) {
     alert('tooltip');
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('title', ''});        
 }
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to check your input is disabled or not first,
and then going back to label to remove the title.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".label").hover(function() {
                if($(this).children().attr('disabled')) {
                   $(this).attr('title','123'); /*just change 123 to empty '' then can remove your title */
                }
                if($(this).attr('title')) $(this).removeAttr('title');
                /*<del>$('.showtitle').text($(this).attr('title'));*/
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="label" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Test">
        <input type="checkbox" value="disabled" class="input" disabled/>
    </label>

<label class="showtitle"></label>
```

Comment: It changed the title text but it is not rendering the changed text. The problem I am facing is that I have to change or remove the tooltip's title when the mouse is hovering over if the input was set disabled.

Comment: @Gene9y but I think if I set title to empty string, when you hover over that label it will not show any tooltips tab.  
anyway I just change my answer, you can use Jquery removeAttr to remove element attribute

Comment: Thanks all. Somehow, mine was working with 'data-original-title' instead of 'title'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for all input that have disabled attribute or not. but for this solution following code will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".label").hover(function() {
        if($(this).attr('data-toggle')=="tooltip" ) {
            $(this).attr('title','');       
        }
    });
});
<label class="label" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Test">
    <input type="checkbox" value="disabled" class="input" disabled/>
</label>
```

Comment: No, it's not working. It cannot pass the data-toggle attribute and is not setting the title to null either.